# python why are the object properties leaking into one another

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, constructor

consider the following class

```
import random

class MyClass():
    arr = []

    def __init__(self, size):
        for index in range(size):
            self.arr.append(random.random())

        print("the size of the array is : " + str(len(self.arr)))


MyClass(4)
MyClass(3)
MyClass(2)
MyClass(1)
```

The output while running the following code is:

```
the size of the array is : 4
the size of the array is : 7
the size of the array is : 9
the size of the array is : 10
```

It's clearly that every time the constructor gets called, the context is not getting maintained 
instead the array values all seems to get appended into a gloabal variable called `arr`

I want to know why are the object variables not maintaining the context and leaking into each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your code `arr` is defined as a **static** member variable in `MyClass`. In Python these are also called **class variables** (in contrast to instance variable).

If you want to declare a variable in your class, and you want that variable to be confined to the context of an instance, then you want an **instance variable**. To do that you need to edit your code a little bit. Remove the class level declaration of `arr`. and edit **init**(self) to declare `arr` as in:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.arr = []
        for index in range(size):
            self.arr.append(random.random())

        print("the size of the array is : " + str(len(self.arr)))
```

to read more about instance and class variables check the python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: can you post the code to make it into a object varibale?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes to edit this answer!

Comment: but if self.arr needs to be initialised every time on constructor call, then whats the advantage of having a class property!

Comment: There are many uses for "static variables". For example they can be used to count the number of instances of a class. or to share a specific variable among instances of a class where all instances are be able to access it and manipulate it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables