# Why is the argument getting passed in to this python method treated this way?

Tags: python

version: Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]

Setup:

```
class _Mixin:
    def vars_to_dct(self, results=[]):
        dct = self.to_dict()
        for k in dct.keys():
            results.append(k)
        return results


@dataclass
class ClassA(_Mixin):
    a: str = ""
    b: str = ""


@dataclass
class ClassB(_Mixin):
    c: str = ""
    d: str = ""
    e: str = ""
```

Instantiate ClassA and method by itself. This is fine:

```
a = ClassA()
assert ["a", "b"] == a.vars_to_dct()
```

Instantiate ClassB and method by itself. This is fine:

```
b = ClassB()
assert ["c", "d", "e"] == b.vars_to_dct()
```

Instantiate ClassA and ClassB together. This is not fine:

`AssertionError`

```
a = ClassA()
assert ["a", "b"] == a.vars_to_dct()

b = ClassB()
assert ["c", "d", "e"] == b.vars_to_dct()
```

What actually happens:

```
b = ClassB()
assert ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] == b.vars_to_dct()
```

Explicitly redeclaring the argument also works fine:

```
b = ClassB()
assert ["c", "d", "e"] == b.vars_to_dct(results=[])
```

Note: I have tried to apply the answers here to this behaviour:

- [python why are the object properties leaking into one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488394/python-why-are-the-object-properties-leaking-into-one-another)
- [How to avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)

But the difference and my question is: I am **explicitly declaring the argument** to the method.

Why is the argument `results=[]` on the method not recognised when it's run again?

```
    def vars_to_dct(self, results=[]):
```

Can someone confirm for me that it really is official Python behaviour to have variables declared in methods to be "static members"/"class variables"?

Comment: The default value is evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So there's just one default list, which you keep appending to for every instance.

Comment: Yes, it is well-known (albeit surprising to many coming from other languages) that default values are evaluated *once* when a function is defined. They are quite literally simply just stored in `myfunc.__defaults__`